# Logging of changed fields/columns in DB updates

Tags: java, database, postgresql, glassfish, ejb

Our product ecosystem: **Web/Enterprise Application** using **EJB** in **Glassfish V3** and **PostgreSQL 8.4**.

How to detect which field was changed without using dirty flags or re-reading the same record(s) before updating it ?
Why: For audit purpose/logging

Any recipes or ideas ?

Thanks
Sven

Comment: are you using JPA? If yes, what provider?

Comment: JPA 2.0, so its EclipseLink, Toplink as alternative

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, write trigger on UPDATE that compares values in NEW and OLD, and reports somehow what has changed.

Comment: not sure how to return the result into the application layer where the logging is done.

Comment: If you're doing logging in application, make the comparison also in application. Or just do the audit logging in database - it's simpler.